# How to use the _Qt python module?

Tags: python, qt, module

There is a python module called "_Qt". PyQt is not what I want. I was wondering if there was any documentation for the _Qt module installed with python as a standard module. I have a mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's QuickTime, nothing to do with Qt.

In your question it's not really clear if you intended to use Qt or QuickTime.

Comment: What about the _tkinter module. Is that documented?